# posting values to textbox using java servlet in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, servlets, textbox

I am creating a java servlet which should get a number from a textbox (created using  using HTML) calculate its factorial and when i will press submit button (also created using HTML) it should calculate and display the factorial in another textbox which i have created.

**Problem** I have successfully retrieved the number from the first textbox (using request.getParameter) and calculated it factorial. Now the problem is that i am unable to post the calculated factorial in that 2nd textbox.

Plz help me what should i do?
Thank in advance!
Here is the code:
**servlet:**

```
package factorial;

import java.io.*;

import javax.servlet.Servlet;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.apache.jasper.tagplugins.jstl.core.Out;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class fact
 */
@WebServlet("/fact")
public class fact extends HttpServlet implements Servlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public fact() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        long number = Long.parseLong((request.getParameter("num")));
        long fact=1;
        while(number>1){
            fact=fact*number;
            number--;
        }

        //request.setAttribute("factorial", fact); //***this is not working***
        //out.println(fact);
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

}
```

**HTML Code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Factorial</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="fact" method="get">
    Enter a number: <input type="text" name="num">
    <input type="submit"/>
    Factorial <input type="text" id="factorial" name="factorial"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: if both the textbox are in the same html file then i think use of ajax will solve your problem

Comment: @javaBeginner he is obviously doing excercises with plain, oldschool servlets. Don't confuse him by recommending a _client side_ technology, when all he wants is to do it the old way, sending the request and loading the whole page...

Comment: You have to render the whole page again, and set the value to the textbox while rendering the page. However, please read the [FAQ], this question in this form, without code is not fit for this site...

Comment: thankyou javaBeginner, but as ppeterka said i am new to this and dont know what ajax is.
and ppeterka which code should i post the one in java servlet???

Answer (score 0):

store the value in request or session attributes as `request.setAttribute("name",value)` or `session.setAttribute("name", value)`. and in JSP, retrieve them using `request.getAttribute("name")` or `session.getAttribute("name")`

Comment: Raghavendra sir thanks for the reply. I just want to know what does "name" from HTML represents here?
is it the name i used for 2nd textbox i.e. name="factorial"???

Comment: is it impossible to do :(

Comment: name can be anything. But in jsp, get the attribute value to the local variable and assign it to the respective text box value like: Long factValue = (Long) request.getAttribute("factorial"); and in the text box add a value attribute as value="<%=factValue.toString()%>"